# google sheets import internal error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets

Hi I've had this problem since last year. I tried all the solutions everyone offered elsewhere (ie copy paste the whole thing to a new sheet), but even then, after a couple of weeks the same problem arises (without any changes on the sheet). Google has not fixed this yet. I know from other forums, etc that lots of people have the same problem for years now...

HELP !

I have used google sheets to import stock prices from bloomberg.com and I am using the following importxml formula for a number of stocks (each formula pulls the data from near identical web pages). I only use 15-20 similar formulas, so i can't be a processing power issue. The problem is that by a completely random rate, some formulas return #N/A "import internal error" whereas others return the result just fine. And it's not the same ones every time I open the sheet !!

This is the sample formula:

=ImportXml("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/BND:US","//div[@class='price']")

May I stress that the xpath is correct and the formula DOES work normally.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Bloomberg to get some bond information I just can't get anywhere else. I doubt it is a Bloomberg issue. ImportXML can just be a bit quirky. For basic information, I find Google Finance to be much more consistent. I would use:

```
=googlefinance("BND","Price")
```

Comment: thanks! it seems to be working better... I'll have to recheck in a couple of weeks